# Import data from a CSV file without id as column

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, csv, export-to-csv

I would like to know if it's possible to import data but with a table that does not have a column named **id**

My import are doing fine with every table that contained a **column** id but with the one that does not contained a column **id** it does not work. I got a row_error saying :
 `Error: 'id'`

**Model** that can't be imported

```py
class CustomizingObject(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, unique=True, help_text="Human readable code")
```

**My function**

```py
from import_export import resources

lo_resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=lo_resource_to_import)() # lo_resource_to_import is the model
with open(lv_local_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv_data = f.read()
    lt_dataset = tablib.Dataset().load(csv_data, 'csv')

result = lo_resource.import_data(lt_dataset, dry_run=True)
if not result.has_errors():
    result = lo_resource.import_data(lt_dataset, dry_run=False)
    Logger.Info("import", 2) # Import over
else :
    Logger.Error("import", 3, lv_local_filename) # Input file {} has error
    for ld_error in result.row_errors():
        Logger.Error("import", 5, ld_error[1][0].error) # Error: {}
```

Comment: you have to set `PrimaryKey` field in your script. if you using a popular library, search in documents of that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you are using

Comment: I have edit the question, and for information i'm using resources from Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provide a `import_id_fields` so we can specify fields that we wants to import. Without it, it always look for a field `ID`.

The solution was to emcapsulate my class with `resources.ModelResource` and specify `import_id_fields`.

```py
class CustomizingObjectResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomizingObject
        import_id_fields = ('code',)
        fields = ('code')
```

**My function**

```py
# specific is a parameter of my function here specific = CustomizingObjectResource
if specific is not None:
    lo_resource = specific()
else:
    lo_resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=lo_resource_to_import)()
with open(lv_local_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv_data = f.read()
    lt_dataset = tablib.Dataset().load(csv_data, 'csv')

result = lo_resource.import_data(lt_dataset, dry_run=True)
if not result.has_errors():
    result = lo_resource.import_data(lt_dataset, dry_run=False)
    Logger.Info("import", 2) # Import over
else :
    Logger.Error("import", 3, lv_local_filename) # Input file {} has error
    for ld_error in result.row_errors():
        Logger.Error("import", 5, ld_error[1][0].error) # Error: {}
```